# 2D RPG Fantasy PC Flash Game with 3 Characters - Ghost, Witch and Vampire

Tags: story-identification, vampire, ghost, witches, games

I couldn't find the game or the name of the game I played in the 2000s and was looking to see if anyone remember it.

It wasn't a very popular game, and I believe I played it on PC on an online website for flash games. It has similar art style as "The Dead Case" by Retshark, as it is 2D with the hand drawn lines at the background and for the characters, simplistic with thick lines and kind of looks like you drew it from paint (not an insult btw I love the game). The ghost in the game has similar colour scheme as Spooky in "Spooky's House of Jump Scares" by Lag Studios. You can move around with your controls and click on different items on the screen to interact with it.

The story starts with seeing this satan like figure kind of destroying villages and taking over, and the girls have to stand up against it and fight it. You choose between three characters: the ghost, the witch and the vampire.

The ghost is blue and after obtaining an item specific to her, she will be able to become invisible. She is kind of cynical and is the weakest of all characters. The witch is quite happy and she can transform into a cat after obtaining an item specific to her. The vampire can transform into a bat after obtaining an item specific to her as well.

The story goes on with you exploring different parts of the village, obtaining information, looking for the other two ladies and gaining powers for yourself before you go fight the creature with them.

I remember the art style distinctly as it is not very common and I really enjoyed the game. I know this game was popular enough to have a walk through since I was stuck at a level before. Hopefully someone here stumbled upon this game before, like I did, and remember the name of it, unlike me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a nicely detailed question. I previously was looking for *The Dead Case* at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87125/flash-point-and-click-game-where-you-are-a-newly-risen-ghost?rq=1 and they found it, so there is hope. :) Please stick around to check for answers and people asking for clarifying details.

Comment: Does your character choice last throughout the playthrough? Do you get to choose times to swap? Do some parts force you to pick a particular character?

Comment: Hello @FuzzyBoots, I actually saw your question for The Dead Case, which is why I decided to search for the game here :) And I think the character choice last throughout the play through? Because I remember playing it several times in order to get different experience for different characters. But I think in the end you are allowed to play more than one or you need abilities of the others?  I am trying hard to remember but it has been a while now :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been looking for this game for a really long time, and I finally found it!

It's called [Devil's Triad](https://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/195851), and I've linked it for you :)

[image]

Comment: If you are the same person as the original poster, you can merge your accounts as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts so that you can self-accept. :)

Comment: Oh my goodness this is it!! Thank you so much!!!!!!!! This is amazing and you have no idea how grateful I am lol!!! xxxxxx Hats off to you and your detective skills!!! :D Thank you againnnnnn!!! :D